# Robust Firewall VPN product/solution for Linux clients

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

We use Citrix at work and I am able to vpn in with Ubuntu 14.04 but am having issues with 16.04. I think this is silly that once a distro gets updated it becomes a pain to get working and I have to revert my OS just to restore remote connectivity. There has got to be a more stable solution I'm not aware of.

Hoping  someone could recommend a firewall or vpn product or opensource solution that has good vpn support for Linux clients.

Comment: What's wrong with OpenVPN + UFW?

Comment: @kazwolfe Probably nothing I just know nothing about it. What is UFW? Is openvpn the client I install on my OS and UFW an appliance our IT staff can install?

Comment: UFW is just a firewall program that is effectively a frontend to `iptables`. See [this DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04). As for OpenVPN, it comes in a client and a server mode. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). These aren't like physical boxes or other hardware appliances/devices. They're apps that anyone can install on any Ubuntu server. If you want a router or security gateway, that's a different (and more complicated) matter.

Comment: @KazWolfe Your comment is what I was looking for. If you don't think this question ought to be deleted you can create a question that I'd happily mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just installing the OpenVPN server and UFW on a standard Ubuntu server? It isn't a traditional security gateway or full-fledged "appliance" like what you might be used to, but it gets the job done very well with minimal overhead.

Both [UFW](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [OpenVPN](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) are very easy to set up (see the links), though they do require a specific (but fortunately, common) configuration.

For example, the firewall installation on a standard server will only protect the server itself, not the network as a whole. If you want this full protection, you will probably need an enterprise gateway of some sort. You will, however, need to discuss this with your IT team to find a solution that will fit your company's requirements.

---

Starting with UFW, most Ubuntu servers will already have this installed on them. If not, run this command:

```
sudo apt install ufw
```

UFW at its core is pretty simple to use. To allow SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS for example:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw allow 80
sudo ufw allow 443
```

This will take effect when you run `sudo ufw enable`. Unlike `iptables`, these rules will persist through a reboot.

OpenVPN is far more complicated. I would *highly* advise you read the above-linked post, as it dives very deep into all of the configs that you will likely need to touch. There are *many* guides available online if that one doesn't work. Either way, to install it:

```
sudo apt install openvpn-server
```

A sample config file is available at `/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf`, and can be played with to your heart's content. As it's a service, you'll need to restart it (`systemctl restart openvpn.service`) on any changes to the real config under `/etc/openvpn`.

It is also important to note that the act of just installing OpenVPN on a server is not enough. If your company network is common, your server will be hiding behind a NAT and you will need to have your IT department set up a port forward for this server so that you can access it from the world. In this case, be sure to test and set up any relevant security/firewall systems *before* exposing the server to the Internet.